# How do I display variables, which are multiples of 3, using JS?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

Here is my code. I am able to display numbers 1-100, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the code to skip over numbers which are not multiples of 3. I have a feeling that I have to use logical operators.

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++ ){
   document.write(i + "<br>");
 if ( i == 100) {
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Modulo operator (%) can be used to check divisibility.

Comment: You `if` is useless and not needed. `for (var i = 3; i < 100; i += 3);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use modulus:

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        document.write(i + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Or start at 3 and increase by 3:

```
for ( var i = 3 ; i < 100 ; i = i + 3 ) {
    document.write(i + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only display use the Modulus function.

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
{
    do stuff;
}
```

this works as modulus gives the remainder of integer division.

So a number divisible by 3 has a 0 remainder.